# Margin bottom on each short children of children divs

Tags: jquery

I have 3 `.items_row` divs, that each contains 4 `.item` and each `.item` contains an `.item_img`. I'm using the following script to find the tallest `.item_img` in each `.item` in each `.items_row`, and add a bottom margin to the shortest ones which is the tallest `.item_img` height minus the height of each shortest.

```
$('.items_row').each(function(){
    var tallestimg = -1;
    $(this).children().each(function() {
        $(this).find('.item_img').each(function(i) {
            tallestimg = $(this).height() > tallestimg ? $(this).height() : tallestimg;
            if ($(this).height() < tallestimg) {
                $(this).css({ 'margin-bottom': tallestimg - $(this).height() });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The script works exactly as I want but in the case the tallest `.item_img` div is not in the first `.item` div the shortest divs before it don't get the `margin-bottom` at all. For example if the tallest `.item_img` div is in the second `.item` of an `.items_row`, the `.item_img` preceding it ignores the `margin-bottom`. Any ideas?

Comment: post your markup as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution doesn't work because you are not setting the margin-bottom for the images before the tallest. If your images are sorted from shortest to tallest, all the images will have margin-bottom = 0.

You should first search for the tallest image, and then iterate through the images again to apply the required margin-bottom.

I think this should work:

```
$('.items_row').each(function(){
    var tallestimg = -1;
    $(this).children().each(function() {
        $(this).find('.item_img').each(function(i) {
            tallestimg = $(this).height() > tallestimg ? $(this).height() : tallestimg;            
        });
    });

    $(this).children().each(function() {
        $(this).find('.item_img').each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).height() < tallestimg) {
                $(this).css({ 'margin-bottom': tallestimg - $(this).height() });
            }
        });
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.items_row').each(function() {
    var $rowItems = $('.items', this)

    // get the height of the tallest .item in the row
    var maxHeight = $rowItems.map(function(index, element) {
        return $(element).height();
    }).get();

    // apply the required margin-bottom to each .item
    $rowItems.each(function() {
        $(this).css({ 'margin-bottom': maxHeight - $(this).height() })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the tallest image:

```
var max_height = Math.max.apply(
    null,
    $('.item_img').map(function(ix, el){ 
        return $(el).height(); 
    }).get()
)
```

Then apply the margin:

```
$('.item_img').each(function(){
    $(this).css({'margin-bottom': max_height - $(this).height()});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/pPTkL/1/

```
$('.items_row').each(function() {
 var height= -1;
 $(this).find('.item_img').each(function() {
     height = Math.max(height, $(this).height()); 
 });

 $(this).find('.item_img').each(function() {
     $(this).css('margin-bottom',(height - $(this).height()));
 });
});​
```